# Able to show jpg images in my app on the simulator but not on my iPod?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Not sure why I can show jpg images in the simulator but not when I load the app to my iPod?

```
uiivHelp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"memoryB.jpg"]];
[self.view addSubview:uiivHelp];

[uiivHelp sizeToFit];
uiivHelp.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400);//460
uiivHelp.hidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazing... the simulator is not case sensitive where as the iPod is case sensitive for file loading... memoryB.jpg vs memoryB.JPG

Comment: That actually depends on the filesystem you are using. By default, OSX is installed on a non case-sensitive FS.